# How to deploy Rails 3 on FreeBSD 8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, freebsd

I'm pretty nooby to FreeBSD and I only have worked before with ROR on Mac OS and Heroku. Now I've got VPS with installed FreeBSD 8 and found it problematic to install ror 3 with mongrel properly. Google gives me only really outdated guides, so I was wondering, if you guys could recommend me any good link (or recommendations) with step-by-step guide on it.
Many thanks!

Comment: this is serverfault. try apache + mod passenger

Comment: What are the problems you are facing ?

Comment: Do you have the ports tree available?  ( /usr/ports )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# portsnap fetch extract
# cd /usr/ports/www/rubygem-rails
# make install clean
```